# Makefile cache creating false positive outcome

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a make target, which i usually need to run twice to get accurate outcome. I.e the 1st run if accurate thenn on the 2nd run, if the variable is changed, it still displays the previous output, which is wrong, is there  a way to get rid of cache or clear it in between.

```
.PHONY:check-tf-lint
check-tf-lint: configure ## TF Linting
    $(eval list_of_dir := $(shell cd ${deployment} && ls -ld */ |  awk '{print $$NF}'|  grep -v 'test_cases'| sed 's|/||g'))
    $(shell touch ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt)
    @for i in aws_bot; do \
        make set-tf-version -e infra_module_path=$$i; \
        terraform fmt -check -list=false ${deployment}/$$i ; \
        if [ "$$?" != "0" ]; then \
            echo "Need Formatting in $$i" >> ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
            terraform fmt -check ${deployment}/$$i >> ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
            echo "" >> ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
        fi \
    done
    $(eval TMP := $(shell (cat ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt | wc -l)))
    echo "${TMP}"
    @if [ "$(TMP)" = "0" ]; then \
        echo "All Good! No Formatting Needed."; \
    else \
        echo "Kindly Format Below Mentioned code and check in Again"; \
        cat ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
    fi
    $(shell rm -rf ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt)
    @if [ "$(TMP)" != "0" ]; then \
        exit 1; \
    fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb: you should never use `eval` or `shell` functions in a make recipe.  If you are doing that it's a pretty sure sign that something has gone wrong somewhere.

In your case the reason you see this behavior is that make will expand *ALL* variables *and functions* for all lines in a recipe before the first line in the recipe is invoked.  So as far as make is concerned your recipe is handled like this:

```
.PHONY:check-tf-lint
check-tf-lint: configure ## TF Linting
        $(eval list_of_dir := $(shell cd ${deployment} && ls -ld */ |  awk '{print $$NF}'|  grep -v 'test_cases'| sed 's|/||g'))
        $(shell touch ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt)
        $(eval TMP := $(shell (cat ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt | wc -l)))
        $(shell rm -rf ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt)
        @for i in aws_bot; do \
            make set-tf-version -e infra_module_path=$$i; \
            terraform fmt -check -list=false ${deployment}/$$i ; \
            if [ "$$?" != "0" ]; then \
                echo "Need Formatting in $$i" >> ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
                terraform fmt -check ${deployment}/$$i >> ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
                echo "" >> ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
            fi \
        done
        echo "${TMP}"
        @if [ "$(TMP)" = "0" ]; then \
            echo "All Good! No Formatting Needed."; \
        else \
            echo "Kindly Format Below Mentioned code and check in Again"; \
            cat ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
        fi
        @if [ "$(TMP)" != "0" ]; then \
            exit 1; \
        fi
```

You should always write your recipes using *shell* facilities and not *make* facilities.  Set *shell* variables, don't use `eval` to set make variables, and run shell commands directly (you're in a recipe after all!) rather than using make's `shell` function.

You may need to put all the lines in a single script (with semicolon / backslash) to allow this to work.  Or consider `.ONESHELL` but that's a much bigger set of changes.

Comment: Thanks a ton for clearing my concept, i was struggling with such false positives for months now, now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me !

```
.PHONY:check-tf-lint
check-tf-lint: ## TF Linting
    $(eval list_of_dir := $(shell cd ${deployment} && ls -ld */ |  awk '{print $$NF}'|  grep -v 'test_cases'| sed 's|/||g'))
    @for i in $(list_of_dir); do \
        make set-tf-version -e infra_module_path=$$i; \
        terraform fmt -check -list=false ${deployment}/$$i ; \
        if [ "$$?" != "0" ]; then \
            echo "Need Formatting in $$i" >> ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
            terraform fmt -check ${deployment}/$$i >> ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
            echo "" >> ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
        fi \
    done
    @if [ -e "${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt" ]; then \
        export MNC=`cat ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt | wc -l`; \
        if [ "$${MNC}" = "0" ]; then \
            echo "All Good! No Formatting Needed."; \
        else \
            echo ""; \
            echo "Kindly Format Below Mentioned code and check in Again"; \
            cat ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
        fi; \
        rm -rf ${quality-metrics}/formatting.txt; \
        if [ "$${MNC}" != "0" ]; then \
            exit 1; \
        fi \
    fi
```